# Android SQLite CREATE VIEW - is view "permanent" or does it have to be recreated?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

i programatically  create a view in SQLite,

```
db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_TABLE_003);
```

with syntax

```
"create view if not exists inspection AS SELECT * FROM praga LEFT JOIN areaPraga ON areaPraga.Id_Praga = praga.Id_Praga"
```

yet it seems that said view gets destroyed (unlike tables in SQLite db) when app closes.

Must i recreate a view every time i want to use it or is it permanent, like a table?

Answer (score 0):

PERMANENT.  Checking database tables and views, using

```
sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' OR type='view'",null);
Log.i(TAG,"what lies inside database\r\n"+DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));
```

i was able to verify that, even after shutting down and restarting app, the view was still available.